# How to make two sides edges with keeping scale mode Aspect fill?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to make edges for the two sides in the scene by using this code

```
let leftEdge : SKNode = SKNode()

    leftEdge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointZero , toPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height + 100))

    leftEdge.position = CGPointZero;
    leftEdge.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = EdgeCategory;
    leftEdge.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BubblesCategory;

    self.addChild(leftEdge)

    // right edge
        let rightEdge : SKNode = SKNode()

    rightEdge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointZero , toPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height + 100))

    rightEdge.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, 0.0);
    rightEdge.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = EdgeCategory;
    rightEdge.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BubblesCategory;

    self.addChild(rightEdge)
```

It works fine if i use `ResizeFill` scale mode but i want to make the mode `AspectFill` so how i can make the edges with keeping the mode `AspectFill`?

Comment: Where are you using those `fills`s? In some image code, not shown in the snippet?

Comment: which fills do u mean ?

Comment: "`ResizeFill`", "`AspectFill`", you mention them in the text, but nowehere in the code!?

Comment: scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill